# What is the most efficient way to find the first and last entry of an entity in SQL?

Tags: sql

I was asked this question in an interview. A table, trips, contains the following columns( customer_id, start_from, end_at, start_at_time, end_at_time), with data structured so that each trip is stored as a separate row and a part of the table looks like  this:[image: this] How would you find  the list of all the customers who started yesterday from point A and ended yesterday at point P?

I provided solution using windowing functions that identified the list of all customers that started their day at A and then did an inner join of a list of these customers with the customers who ended their day at P( using the same windowing functions).

The solution I gave was this:

```
SELECT a.customer_id
FROM
  (SELECT a.customer_id
   FROM
     (SELECT customer_id,
             start_from,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                ORDER BY start_at_time ASC) AS rnk
      FROM trips
      WHERE to_date(start_at_time)= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, 1) ) AS a
   WHERE a.rnk=1
     AND a.start_from='A' ) AS a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT a.customer_id
   FROM
     (SELECT customer_id,
             end_at,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                ORDER BY end_at_time DESC) AS rnk
      FROM trips
      WHERE to_date(end_at_time)= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, 1) ) AS a
   WHERE a.rnk=1
     AND a.end_at='P' ) AS b ON a.customer_id=b.customer_id
```

My interviewer said my solution was correct but there is a more efficient way to solve this problem. I've searching and trying to find a more efficient way but I could not find one so far. Can you suggest a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'd have gotten the min start time and max end time (for the specified date) for each customer in the table, then joined back to the table twice to get the start and end locations that went along with those times, and finally filtered to only those starting and ending at the specified locations. Additionally, I would not have used `to_date`, calling any function on field values in a condition negates the ability to take advantage of indexes; you would have been better off with `start >= [yesterday's date] AND end < [today's date]`.

Comment: @Uueerdo, That includes 2 self joins, then further joining the results to get the start and end point together in a row and then further filtering for the required criteria. Will that be faster than the solution I gave?

Comment: Your use of window functions probably ends up selecting all the data for the date, then sorts it for each customer, takes the first sorted value for each customer; then does it again and joins the two results together. But while writing this, it occurs to me I didn't even need to reference end... it can be done completely with min and max starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use `first_value()` for this:

```
select t.customer_id
from (select t.*,
             first_value(start_from) over (partition by customer_id order by start_at_time) as first_start,
             first_value(end_at) over (partition by customer_id order by start_at_time desc) as last_end
      from t
      where start_at_time >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, 1) and
            start_at_time < CURRENT_DATE
     ) t
where first_start = start_from and  -- just some filtering so select distinct is not needed
      first_start = 'A' and
      last_end = 'P';
```

I should add that many databases support an equivalent function for aggregation, and I would use that instead.

This assumes that starts are not repeated.  To be safe, you can add `select distinct`, but there is a performance hit for that.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized version of what I would probably have done:

```
SELECT fandl.a
FROM (
   SELECT a, MIN(start) AS t0, MAX(start) AS tN
   FROM someTable
   WHERE start >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, 1) AND start < CURRENT_DATE
   GROUP BY a
) AS fandl
INNER JOIN someTable AS st0 ON fandl.a = st0.a AND fandl.t0 = st0.start
INNER JOIN someTable AS stN ON fandl.a = stN.a AND fandl.tN = stN.start
WHERE st0.b1 = 'A' AND stN.b2 = 'P'
;
```

*Using the date function you did, since you did not specify sql dialect.*

Note that, in many RDBMS, if there is an (a, start) index, the subquery and joins can be done with the index alone; actual table access would only be required for the final WHERE evaluation.